# F-Test without a white noise process

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study

In Section 3 of *[Spurious Regressions in Econometrics](http://wolfweb.unr.edu/~zal/STAT758/Granger_Newbold_1974.pdf)* (1974), by C.W.J. Granger and P. Newbold, the authors present a standard linear regression model and F-Test.

Then they discard the assumption that the dependent variable is characterized by a white noise process.  This results in the inability of the null hypothesis of the F-Test to be true.  In their words:

"However, to the extent that the $Y_t's$ do not constitute a white noise process, the null hypothesis (8) *cannot* be true, and tests of it are inappropriate."

(8) $H_0:\beta_1=\beta_2=...=\beta_{k-1}=0$

Why does changing the white noise assumption disable the null hypothesis of the F-Test to be true?